Error when deserializing strum Enum with Serde
Folks, I'm getting stuck on a pretty simple issue using strum and serde crates is Rust.
First of all, I have this struct below:
use enums::Timezone;
use crate::CustomError;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{from_str, to_string};

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub struct LocaleConfig {
    pub timezone: Timezone,
    pub language: String,
}
impl LocaleConfig {
    fn from_json_str(json_str: &str) -> Result<Self, CustomError> {
        from_str(json_str)?
    }

As you can see, I'm using a Timezone enum that follows:
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use strum_macros::{Display, EnumIter, EnumString};
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, PartialEq, EnumString, EnumIter, Display)]
pub enum Timezone {
    #[serde(rename = "GMT-12")]
    #[strum(serialize = "GMT-12")]
    UTCm12,
    #[serde(rename = "GMT-11")]
    #[strum(serialize = "GMT-11")]
    UTCm11,
...
    #[serde(rename = "GMT+11")]
    #[strum(serialize = "GMT+11")]
    UTCp11,
    #[serde(rename = "GMT+12")]
    #[strum(serialize = "GMT+12")]
    UTCp12,
}

The problem is that when I try to deserialize this:
let json = r#"{"timezone":"GMT-5","language":"en-US"}"#;

with LocaleConfig::from_json_str I get the following error:
Custom Error { title: "Serde Json Error", description: "unknown variant `timezone`, expected `Ok` or `Err` at line 1 column 11" }

As you can infer, CustomError is just a wrapper for my crates error. Also, please note that LocaleConfig and Timezone are located in different modules.
enums/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "enums"

[dependencies]
serde = { workspace = true }
serde_json = { workspace = true }
strum = { version = "0.26.2" }
strum_macros = { version = "0.26.2" }

config/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "config"
[dependencies]
serde = { workspace = true, features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = { workspace = true }
enums = { workspace = true }

And finally, my virtual manifest uses the versions that follow:
[workspace.dependencies.serde]
serde = { version = "1.0.197", features = ["derive"] }

[workspace.dependencies.serde_json]
version = "1.0.114"

What am I missing here? I mean, when I run: Timezone::from_str("GMT-5");, I get the correct enum, but I understand that the desererialize fn being run may differ.
Any insights on this matter?

Can we see the data you're deserializing from?

Your issue is how you're calling it:
fn from_json_str(json_str: &str) -> Result<Self, CustomError> {
    from_str(json_str)?
}

from_str(json_str) returns a Result<T, Error> where T is to be determined from context. from_str(json_str)? will return early with the error if there is one, otherwise pass on the value in the Ok variant. That value in the Ok variant (so not the outer Result, but an instance of its type T) is what will be returned from this function, and so it must be Result<Self, Error>, which is to say that you've inadvertently told serde that you're deserializing into a Result<Self, Error>, not a Self. (Or equivalently, that from_str is to return a Result<Result<Self, Error>, Error>.)
To fix this, write Ok(from_str(json_str)?). Since Ok(from_str(json_str)?) must have type Result<Self, Error>, from_str(json_str)? must have type Self.

Or alternatively, from_str(json_str).map_err(From::from) should work: it can be used more finely, but usually ? will just early-return with a conversion of the error, so you can simply perform that conversion explicitly.
